# D3 path working on Mozilla, not working on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, d3.js

And no, it is not a cross-resource error. The code works on Mozilla Firefox and not on Chrome, IE, or Safari.

I have uploaded the code as a gist and it can be tested here (check console for errors): https://bl.ocks.org/moman822/7a05fb2becde5f2081e9bdb4ee5c9511. Check the checkbox then click the button to activate the graph animation.

I have narrowed the error down to the appending of the path variables. This is the section where it goes wrong (line 199, outputs logged to console).

```
svg.selectAll('path')
        .data(datNestTemp, function(d){console.log(d); return d})
        .enter()
        .append('path')
            .attr('d',function(d){console.log(lineScale(d.values)); return lineScale(d.values)})
            .attr('class',function(d){return d.key.replace(/ /g,'')})
            ...
```

`lineScale` looks like this:

```
lineScale = d3.line()
            .curve(d3.curveCardinal())
```

On Mozilla, the path is parsed correctly. However, on Chrome the path is not parsed correctly, instead outputting this string (shown by `console.log` and error output):

```
MNaN,512.1796016898008CNaN,512.1796016898008,NaN,508.7715147857574,NaN,508.7715147857574CNaN,508.7715147857574,NaN,502.3716757191712,NaN,502.3716757191712CNaN,502.3716757191712,NaN,495.0533896600282,NaN,495.0533896600282CNaN,495.0533896600282,NaN,490.1222289277811,NaN,490.1222289277811CNaN,490.1222289277811,NaN,489.2205190102595,NaN,489.2205190102595CNaN,489.2205190102595,NaN,486.3940454636894,NaN,486.3940454636894CNaN,486.3940454636894,NaN,481.
```

etc.

I am at a loss for why this works on Mozilla and not Chrome. Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome your timeScale scale is incorrect, more specifically its domain is `[NaN, NaN]`. You are trying to instantiate date with dateString but that string is not in  the right format - read more about [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Compare the following code in Chrome and FF:

```
[new Date('2005,0,1'), new Date('2016,0,1')]
```

In FF that array can be parsed to date, in Chrome it contains invalid dates.

To sum up, you need to create a correct time scale, e.g. like this:

```
  var min = d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return (+d.Year)  + ',0,1'
  }).split(',')

  var max = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return +d.Year  + ',0,1'
  }).split(',')

  timeScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([new Date(min[0], min[1], min[2]), new Date(max[0], max[1], max[2])])
    .range([0, width])
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/devmzgwj/